# How to calculate mysql tables/database size

Tags: mysql

I am little confused. I have to estimate the size of the table to fit 2 million rows. I have no idea how much space primary and secondary indexes takes. Especially with composite primary and secondary indexes. Structure of the table is something like

Database Engine: innodb

```
create table abc(

a  int,
b  varchar(30),
c  char(10),
d  bigint(8),

FOREIGN KEY(a) 
        REFERENCES af(a_id) 
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
primary key(a,b,c)
)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_abc
  ON abc
    ( a ASC, d  ASC);

CREATE INDEX idx_abc2
  ON abc
    ( d );
```

Please help

Sonu

Comment: With only 2 million rows and each row only about 50 bytes, this is not worth worrying about. more so if you drop idx_abc2 and change idx_abc to (d ASC, a ASC)

Comment: that is just an estimation to understand the sizing part. data will be very big.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size for data/indexes using **mysql.innodb_index_stats**.
Warning, the size is given in pages units => You must multiply it by the pagesize which is usually of 16K.

Comment: Please note that the table is empty. I need to estimate prior to the data inserted into the table.

Answer (score 0):

To do an exact estimation you need to create a copy of the table and generate 2 000 000 volatile data into it, representing the actual size. Measure the table along with indexes as shown in other answers and then, knowing the answer, you can remove the copy.

If preciseness is not as important in your case, then multiply the number of bytes a record will occupy with the number of records and do the same with indexes.

record * 2 000 000 + index * 2 000 000 ~= 50 * 2 000 000 + 60 * 2 000 000 = 110 * 2 000 000 = 22 000 000

Comment: I don't mind if the space is on little bit higher side. i come to know that for primary index does not take any space. is that true even if it is a composite primary key? And what is the way to calculate the secondary index size?

Comment: @Sunil, actually as the table increases, the size of the primary key increases as well. When there is no primary key, InnoDB creates a hidden clustered index, this is why it seems the index does not add to size, but as a matter of fact it does, however, the fact that a hidden index compensates for it, adding some size to the table as well is misleading. Read more here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44520/does-the-size-of-the-primary-key-contribute-to-table-size